# I can't remove the space above and below a paragraph

Tags: html, css, padding, margin, line-height

I can't remove the space above and below a paragraph that only consists of the letter "I" at the top of my Web Page.

I have already tried to remove it with the "margin" and "padding" properties but it is not changed. Also I have tried, for the property "line-height", the value 1 so that the line height exactly matches the size of the text and it doesn't work either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Came</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://fontlibrary.org/face/kolar" type="text/css"/> 
<style>
        
body{
background-color:black;
color:white;}

.photo{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
border:5px solid white;}

.initial{
font-size:500px;
line-height:1;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
```

}

```
.main{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;}


h1{
font-family:KolarExtraBold;
font-size:20px;
border:solid 3px red;
width:65%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom:3px;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="photo">

<p class="initial">I</p>

</div>


<div class="main">
<h1><strong>CSS</strong> The Manual</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

elements generally have margins and / or padding. You can set those to zero in a stylesheet.

```
p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

Semantically speaking, however, it is fairly unusual to have a list of paragraphs.

Comment: Hi John, I have just added "padding-top" and "padding-bottom" to .initial but it doesn't change at all. Thanks

Comment: You can use !important for both padding-top or margin-top thanks

Answer (score 0):

tag has default margin of 1em from top and botton. So you need to explicit define margin and padding both equal to 0, which can be done in 2 ways.

```
 p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
```

or by removing margin and padding like this

```
<p class="initial my-0 py-0">I</p>
```

Comment: `my-0` and `py-0` are Bootstrap/Tailwind classes, why do you think, from the given code, those are installed?

Answer (score 0):

The user agent also adds styling to paragraph elements:

```
p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

You can add a rule for `p` elements to remove this margin.

You will still have space above en below the letter after you remove the margin. This is due to the line height you set. This line height needs to accommodate different letters so it is normal to expect space above and below your letters. If you just want this letter and as little space above and below it you can set the line height to `.655`.

```
.initial {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: .655;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it like this ->

```
<p class="initial my-0 py-0">I</p>
```

where my stands for margin top and margin bottom and
py stands for padding top padding top and padding bottom

Comment: `my-0` and `py-0` are Bootstrap/Tailwind classes, why do you think, from the given code, those are installed?