# Contact form 7: I want to run PHP code after submitting. Is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Contact form 7: How can I run PHP code after submitting? Is it possible?

I have PHP curl code. I want to run it, but how can I do it?

My PHP code:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'chatId' => '9011111@c.us',
    'mentions' => array(
        '9011111@c.us'
    ),
    'text' => 'Hi there!',
    'session' => 'default'
);


$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
        'content' => json_encode($data)
    )
);


$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents('http://1.1.1.1:3000/api/sendText', false, $context);

echo $result;
?>
```

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to execute custom PHP code after a form submission with Contact Form 7 in WordPress. However, to integrate custom PHP code like yours, you need to hook into Contact Form 7's wpcf7_before_send_mail action. This action allows you to run custom code before the email is sent, which is essentially right after the form submission.

Here's how you can do it:

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin. This code hooks into the wpcf7_before_send_mail action and executes your custom PHP code.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'custom_action_after_form_submit' );

function custom_action_after_form_submit($contact_form) {
    $title = $contact_form->title();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    // Check if this is the form you want to trigger your action on
    // You can remove this if check if you want it to apply to all forms
    if ('Your Form Name' == $title) {
        // Your custom PHP code here
        $data = array(
            'chatId' => '9011111@c.us',
            'mentions' => array('9011111@c.us'),
            'text' => 'Hi there!',
            'session' => 'default'
        );

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
                'content' => json_encode($data)
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents('http://1.1.1.1:3000/api/sendText', false, $context);

        // Optionally, you can log the result or perform further actions based on it
        // error_log($result);
    }
}
```

Replace 'Your Form Name' with the actual name of your Contact Form 7 form. This is to ensure the custom code runs only for the specified form. If you want your code to run for every form submission, you can remove the if condition that checks the form title.

Ensure that your server is configured to allow outgoing HTTP requests via file_get_contents and that it supports the PHP stream context options you're using. Some hosting environments disable file_get_contents for URLs or restrict its usage due to security reasons. In such cases, you might need to use cURL or a WordPress-specific HTTP API like wp_remote_post.

Be cautious with security. Make sure your target URL ('http://1.1.1.1:3000/api/sendText') is secure and trusted. Sending data to external servers can introduce security risks.

After adding this code, test your form submission to ensure that your custom PHP code executes as expected and the external API call is made successfully.

Comment: You should use wp_remote_post instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGTP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You'll need to use a WordPress hook, `wpcf7_mail_sent`, to do it.

You need to wrap your cURL code into a function and then use the hook as follows:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_function');
```

Comment: The other answer is better and more complete.

Comment: @Howard E: Well, it was generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar). Have you verified it actually works? That is, actually ran it, tested it, and verified the result? On what system? What versions of PHP, WordPress, Linux, etc.?

Comment: Not convinced? Look at [the writing style before December 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026512/i-cant-remove-the-space-above-and-below-a-paragraph/66026565#66026565) (e.g., a terse, lazy, and moronic writing style).

Comment: All I'm saying here is that this was the accepted answer, and it shows nothing other than a hook.  The other answer which may or may not have been written by a bot, has more information than the accepted answer.  The question is also low quality if you ask me. It shows little effort and probably has answers already.

Comment: I gave him a possible solution for the problem. If he doesn't know how to apply it, the answer serves as a direction on what to study to overcome the issue and achieve the desired solution (and learn it!). We are here to help and provide ideas, not to do someone's code; if this is the case, he should hire me instead. Answers like the 'complete 'one, clearly generated by AI, don't help anything in the learning process and development, and they are forbidden by Stack Overflow policy.